# App crashes when rotating Samsung phone

Tags: android, cordova

Has anyone else expereience that the app crashes if the phone is rotated?
I'm running Android 4.0.3 on my Samsung Galaxy 2.

The problem does not occur on HTC or Samsung running Android 2.3.3.

Eclipse debug screen is not showing any errors.

My app is developed using PhoneGap.

Log when I rotate phone:

```
05-25 13:38:09.155: I/GATE(20061): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
05-25 13:38:09.175: D/DroidGap(20061): Origin to allow: http://127.0.0.1*
05-25 13:38:09.175: I/CordovaLog(20061): Found log level DEBUG
05-25 13:38:09.175: I/CordovaLog(20061): Changing log level to DEBUG(3)
05-25 13:38:09.175: I/CordovaLog(20061): Found preference for classicRender
05-25 13:38:09.175: D/DroidGap(20061): DroidGap.onCreate()
05-25 13:38:09.180: D/DroidGap(20061): DroidGap.loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)
05-25 13:38:09.180: D/DroidGap(20061): DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
05-25 13:38:09.205: I/webclipboard(20061): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@4169fae8
05-25 13:38:09.210: D/DroidGap(20061): DroidGap.init()
05-25 13:38:09.260: D/PluginManager(20061): init()
05-25 13:38:09.280: D/WML_SISO(20061): InitPasteboardJni
05-25 13:38:09.280: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(20061): Ignore this event
05-25 13:38:09.730: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20061): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-25 13:38:09.790: I/GATE(20061): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
05-25 13:38:09.810: I/GATE(20061): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
```

Comment: Please post your LogCat record.

Comment: whenever the screen is rotate ,then its orientation will changed , so may be at the time of orientation changed event your code throw some exception, so the application is crash, it is easy to find the bug if you send the error log

Comment: Maybe your background thread is running and post some changes on UI thread when it finishes, but orientation change will restart activity and your previous UI thread has been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `screenSize` to the `android:configChanges` attribute of your activity and build against at least android-13 target since this value was introduced in API level 13.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to add :     `android:configChanges="orientation"`  in

```
<activity android:name=".activityName"/>
```